# ADAL renewing token using AcquireTokenAsync and existing JWT token

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, access-token, adal, refresh-token

I have a JWT token via initial login that is set to expire in 60mins. I want to renew this token so that the user is not logged out.

For this, am using the `AcquireTokenAsync` call withing that 60mins window using the `UserAssertion`

```cs
public static async Task RenewToken(string resourceUri)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
    var authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    var userAccessToken = authHeader.Substring(authHeader.LastIndexOf(' ')).Trim();
    var userAssertion = new  UserAssertion(userAccessToken);

    // keeps returning the same access token with same expiry
    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, ClientId, userAssertion);

    var userInfo = authResult.UserInfo;
    var apiAccessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
    var expiry = authResult.ExpiresOn.UtcDateTime.ToString("u");
}
```

Is it that the above call with an existing JWT token can be used only once the token is expired?

Any inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code seems you want to refresh token on web api(service) side, on service side you shouldn't renew access tokens.  The client app should do that operation.

With ADAL, your app will get the access and refresh token the first time an end user logs in, then you can use refresh token to get new access token silently ([AcquireTokenSilentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokensilentasync?view=azure-dotnet)) when the access token expires and a refresh token is available & valid.

Access tokens can be refreshed using the refresh-token for a maximum period of time of 90 days with a 14 day expiration sliding window from the date that the access token was acquired by prompting the user.

Checkout our [code sample implementing this scenario for more help](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect). If i misunderstand your scenario , please feel free to let me know .

Comment: Thanks - my scenario is that I have a MVC app hosting my SPA client and a WebAPI to access the resources. I use the OWIN middleware in client to get the access token using the auth code, but in the `AuthenticationResult` returned, there is no `refresh_token`, just the `access_token`. So, am using this `access_token` in client app to request a new token using `AcquireTokenAsync` with `UserAssertion(access_token)`. Is that wrong? The code you mentioned is similar to mine, but am not able to where is the code for refreshing the token on expiry or even the refresh_token itself.

Comment: @sppc42 , in adal v3.x version , it will not expose the refresh token , ADAL  will handle the process for you ,such as check whether refresh token in token cache available& valid , get new access token via refresh token. see [this blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/13/adal-3-didnt-return-refresh-tokens-for-5-months-and-nobody-noticed/) for more details .

Comment: Nan Yu, I have seen that blog and that what I understood that there are no `refresh_tokens` in ADAL now. That's why my code above is using the `access_token` received originally to renew, which is what is mentioned in that blog as well, i.e., to just call the `AcquireTokenAsync` with the `UserAssertion(access_token)`. But that call, if made whilst the token is still valid (not expired) returns me the same token from the cache. So, is it that if this `access_token` gets expired, then only the `AcquireTokenAsync` with this `access_token` will give me a new refreshed token with new expiry date?

Comment: @sppc42 , there is refresh token returned , but adal won't **expose** it to you , adal will handle the refresh token process automatically . Using refresh token to get new access token is the reliable way in your scenario .

Comment: perfect, thanks, i got that. So, is my approach (code) incorrect to refresh the expired access_token? If yes, what should I be doing to refresh the token?

Comment: see [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/TodoListController.cs) line 55-58 , AcquireTokenSilentAsync will handle refresh token process for you (access token expire but refresh token available).

Comment: @sppc42 to your earlier comment about getting back the same access token. ADAL will check the access token expiration, and if still valid, return back that access token from the cache. Now if it sees it is expired, then it will use the refresh token (that Nan Yu mentioned is hidden) to get you a fresh new access token.  The third case is if the refresh token is also expired to which you will receive a `AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException` indicating it is no longer valid. In this case, you'll want to unobtrusively let the user know they need to reauth and issue a new OWIN challenge.